# Cannot paste text in xfce4-terminal

Tags: terminal, paste, xfce

After updating my distribution with Xfce 4.14, I am unable to copy and paste some characters into xfce4-terminal. For example, I can paste "test" but not "test α".

This is highly frustrating. I would prefer if the unknown character was replaced with a question mark, or anything really. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1507179/cant-enter-non-ascii-characters-in-terminal-under-xfce). Paraphrasing that answer:

Is the locale blank? It must be set to xxx.UTF-8 for the terminals to support non-ASCII characters. To enable Unicode support,

- Add a line to `/etc/locale.gen` en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
- Run `locale-gen`
- Add `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to `/etc/locale.conf`
- Log out and log in again

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I did find this suggestion but that is not the cause of the problem. I will update my question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

The following must be set in xfce4-terminal:

```
preferences -> advanced -> default character encoding = UTF-8
```

The LANG environment variable in the shell does not matter, for example mine is set to LANG=en_US, but it's still working.